# Sharepoint 2013 Limit tagging and searching for people in their own OU

Tags: active-directory

Im almost finished setting up our companys Sharepoint farm.
But I got a small question regarding people tagging and searching for each other.
We are a consulting company where the client got their own OU in our Active Directory.

In my case, if I create a site for them and set them to owner, they can search for people in the entire AD instead of only their own OU.

Is there any way to make to keep people only searching in their own OU?
The same goes for "My site". If they access My Site they can tagg a person from another company. This is not intended to work this way is it?

Example:

> 5 OU, Marketing, Economics, Company 1, Company 2, Company 3.
>
> Company 1 can search for people in Company 2.

Is there any way to restrict each OU to themself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created your infrastructure based on one site collection per company, you can use the old tool `stsadm` to configure the sites so they only can search/find users that are members in the site or a specific OU.

[Configure People Picker in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075.aspx)

If you plan do implement this, be careful to document the changes.

Either you go with searching within the site collection membership, or you specify a specific OU for each site collection.

```
stsadm -o setsiteuseraccountdirectorypath -path "OU=Sales,DC=ContosoCorp,DC=local" -url http://central
```

Pay close attention to the difference between allowing one or more OUs in the cmdlt below.

> Because this property specifies only one OU at a time, you should only
>   run the Stsadm **setsiteuseraccountdirectorypath** operation once per site
>   collection. To set multiple OUs at one time, use the Stsadm
>   Peoplepicker-**serviceaccountdirectorypaths** property.